# Adding SWT nature to eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have exported a SWT project from eclipse under Linux and tried to import it under Windows. So far everything works fine except that I seem to have lost the "SWT nature" of the project. Running the project with the SWT gui works fine but when I try to edit the GUI source, I don't have the Source/Design/Bindings tabs below my source window and cannot do any graphical editing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using WindowBuilder. If this is the case, use the following:

Right click class file → Open With → WindowBuilder Editor

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Tanks!